# Eclipse remote development with application arguments

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, remote-access, remote-debugging

I use Eclipse for remote development of C/C++ applications. I want to run the application on remote target which has arguments as inputs from within Eclipse. In my case the input argument is an image. I set the arguments in "Run Configurations" tab.

After the application is Run the argument is append to application executable command but application is not using it.

```
root@imx8qmmek:~# /home/root/tmp/ocv_helloworld lena30.jpg;exit 
Could not open or find the image 
logout
```

[image: Eclipse Run Configurations]

The image itself reside on target within directory the app is run from.

> /home/root/tmp/

When I run that app on remote target from within ssh-terminal though it's OK.

```
root@imx8qmmek:~/tmp# ./ocv_helloworld lena30.jpg
```

[image: Remote target file list]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using full path to image?

/home/root/tmp/lena30.jpg

Comment: Yes, it that case app is executed and no complain that image is missing but no output generated.    /home/root/tmp/ocv_helloworld /home/root/tmp/lena30.jpg;exit
root@imx8qmmek:~# /home/root/tmp/ocv_helloworld /home/root/tmp/lena30.jpg;exit
logout

Comment: Unfortunately, Could not open or find the image

Comment: I redone all program one more and now it seems be working including arguments.